# {Create JSON in JSP} : ATG taglib is free?

Tags: json, apache, jsp, taglib, atg

I need to create a json in a jsp page (preferably without using JavaScript). The ATG taglib is a great solution for my case, but I would to understand if I can use it without paying the ATG license.

The library that I mentioned is:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/atg.taglib.json/json-taglib/0.4.1

In the jsp page I would use the tags and include the taglib with atg namespace:

```
<%@ Taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json"%>
```

The license is Apache 2.0. I want to understand if that guaranteed me the possibility of free use for website projects that will be put into production without ATG license.

Alternatively you know other free solution?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a grey area. The author of the `json-taglib` was employed by ATG at the time of developing the tag-library so they may have some intellectual ownership on this depending on his contract of employment. That said, the [`sourceforge`](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/) project for this suggests that it is open-source and available for use.